# Information in my Thesis incorrectly represented in another publication

Tags: publications, citations, thesis

Recently I came across a publication that referenced my PhD Thesis in a literature survey. The citing is correct, however, the information that they sited is incredibly erroneous. In a table, they claimed that my thesis (in Piezoelectric Energy Harvesting) reported values that it simply did not. The only information apparently from my thesis is reported in a table (Table 3) and nowhere else.

This is [the publication in question](http://www.ioirp.com/Doc/IJIRTSE/Paper/R.Nandhini__R.Indhu__J.Binlin_Jefry__Mrs.S.Kirubaveni.pdf).

Given the journal and publisher, is it worthwhile to attempt to contact the authors to fix the error?

Comment: Volume 1, Issue 1... and the PDF is created by `convertonlinefree.com`. Ha. I think it's fairly safe to say that no one of any repute is likely to take anything the paper says seriously (because the writing and formatting are so bad, if nothing else), but an error is an error. It will be interesting to see whether a predatory journal actually cares, but these articles are usually published without any peer or editor review whatsoever so I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: I've never seen a byline refer to an author by "Mrs." before.  (In other news, I have never heard of "piezoelectric energy".  There are an awful lot more things on heaven and earth than are dreamt of in my philosophy.)  Also, the opening sentence is: "In this modern world we are finding solution to many problems with the growing technologies." I would prefer "It was a dark and stormy night."

Comment: Looks like this publication isn't on the predatory publisher list only because it's so new and crappy.  Ignore it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I needed that laugh this morning.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking along the same lines, but wanted some other opinions.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there really isn't any value in you trying to pursue a correction here, given how sloppy the presentation of the articles is, and how poorly presented the linked article in particular appears to be.

Basically, it would be much ado about nothing; very few people, as the commenters have pointed out, will try to take the published work seriously; even fewer will bother to check the references and dig through them to figure out that they've apparently been grossly mischaracterized by the authors of the paper in question. So, I don't think there's any besmirching of your scientific reputation to worry about.

Moreover, trying to go after these authors or the publisher to make them make changes will most likely prove equally fruitless. There is no quality control or standards involved with the production of the articles, so it seems unlikely that any request for an editorial correction would be honored in a timely manner (or at all).